# Why Hashids can be decoded?

Tags: hashids

I've used this popular library [Hashids](https://hashids.org/php/).

[As this poster mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12278200/3655192),`Hashes produced by these algorithms are designed to be 'one-way'`. Then, why is it possible for a hash value to be decoded?

I've read the documentation (and searched the issues), but don't see why hashes created by this library can be decoded.

I was about to ask this question in the git repo, but this is a question rather than an issue.

Any insight will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You find the reason in the documentation on the project site:

> How does it work?
>   Hashids works similarly to the way integers are converted to hex, but with a few exceptions:
>       The alphabet is not base16, but base base62 by default.
>       The alphabet is also shuffled based on salt.

So, in short, this is not a hash at all, but merely an *alternate encoding*, more similar to a simple substitution cipher than to a hash (which would work as compression function). Which is, of course, pretty trivially reversible.